# Cut off additional \n (new line characters) in a string in R

Tags: string, r, newline

I would like to cut off unneeded additional new line characters in strings using R.
For example, if I have the string:

```
"This is an example test string. \n \n \n"
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
"This is an example test string. \n"
```

Comment: Might any of the `\n` characters be followed by additional text? If so, what would you like something like this to become `"example \n \n continued \n    "`?

Comment: Yes, in fact some of them are. I am actually dealing with the additional problem of cutting a string after the last \n. For example if I have the string "This is an example test string. \n \n \n blah blah more text \n." I would like to cut this into two strings: The first being: "This is an example test string. \n" and the second being: "blah blah more text \n."

Comment: Then add that to the body of your question pronto, or possibly accept Ricardo's answer and then post a new question!

Comment: Okay I will post a new question in 8 minutes when it allows me

Comment: Or just use this (if it does what you need): `x <- "This is an example test string. \n \n \n blah blah more text \n."; pat <- "(?<=\n)[\\s\\n]+";  strsplit(x, pat, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: That does work, except how do I reassign the second part of the string to a new variable? Sorry, a bit new to R. Have something like pat="This is an example test string. \n" and pat2="blah blah more text \n."

Comment: Won't be able to help you there, as it would start turning into a free course on R from the ground up! I can just tell you that `strsplit()` returns a list of character vectors, with one element for each character string in the vector that is passed to it as an argument. Use `[[]]` and `[]` to pick it apart. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 x <- gsub("\\n\\s*", "\n", x)
```

This searches for any newline followed by whitespace and replaces it with a single newline